# how can i boot qemu from a USB device on windows?

Tags: windows, usb, qemu

I found a tool that can do the same thing but I wanted to do it from the command-line

I've tried this command :

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 2G -usb -usbdevice -hda file=\\.\F:\
```

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 4096 -hda \\.\PhysicalDrive2
```

Hard disks can be used with the syntax: \.\PhysicalDriveN where N is the drive number (0 is the first hard disk).

[See also](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/qemu-block-drivers.html?highlight=windows#windows)